# How to copy 2 objects after adding new key in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have 2 objects and I have to copy second objects to new object after adding a new key. for example

```
obj1 = { name: 'a', age:'23'},
obj2 = {city1 : 'x', city2: 'y'},
```

output expected is

```
{name:'a', age: '23', cities: [ {city1: 'x'}, {city2: 'y'}]}
```

what I have tried is

```
obj3 = obj1;
obj3.cities = obj2;
```

but what i got is

```
 { name: 'a', age:'23' }
```

What is the problem with this code and how to copy after adding new key?

Comment: Your question is misleading, this is *not* copy: this is a combination of copy & aggregation since the key `cities` doesn't exist neither in `obj1` not `obj2`. Write a function to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new object by destructuring `obj1` and then adding `cities` to it.

```js
obj1 = {
  name: 'a',
  age: '23'
};

obj2 = {
  city1: 'x',
  city2: 'y'
};

obj3 = {
  ...obj1,
  cities: Object.entries(obj2)
    .map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}))
};

console.log(obj3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use object.assign and then use `Object.keys` on the `obj2`. That will give an array of like `[city1,city2]`. Use map to iterate this array and create the new key and value

```js
let obj1 = {
  name: 'a',
  age: '23'
};
let obj2 = {
  city1: 'x',
  city2: 'y'
};

let obj3 = Object.assign({}, obj1, {
  cities: Object.keys(obj2).map(function(item) {
    return {
      [item]: obj2[item]
    }
  })
});

console.log(obj3)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is answer

```
let obj1 = {
  name: 'a',
  age: '23'
};
let obj2 = {
  city1: 'x',
  city2: 'y'
};

let obj3 = {
    ...obj1, 
    cities: Object.keys(obj2).map(function(item) {
    return {
      [item]: obj2[item]
    }
  })}

console.log(obj3)
```

Answer (score 1):

@31piy's answer is great. So, I'm upvoting him.

However, if you want to do it without modifying the original object, just use Object.prototype.assign method to create a new object out of the composition.

```js
obj1 = {
  name: 'a',
  age: '23'
};

obj2 = {
  city1: 'x',
  city2: 'y'
};

composedObj = Object.assign({}, obj1, {'cities': Object.entries(obj2).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}))})
console.log(composedObj);
```

Comment: My answer no longer modifies `obj1`. This wasn't mentioned in the original post previously.